# Библиотеки для прогнозирования временных рядов

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, library

Не могли бы вы посоветовать методы и, если можно, примеры их применения для прогнозирования временных рядов? fbprophet и LGBMRegressor дают неутешительные результаты.

Про имеющиеся данные: есть день и уровень продаж позиции в этот день; продажи, разумеется, нерегулярны (предположительно, поэтому fbprophet и ошибается, прогнозируя существенно ниже факта). Возможно, решением будет агрегация по неделям.

Пример:

```
            ds     y
0   2018-01-03   7.0
1   2018-01-04  14.0
2   2018-01-05   0.0
3   2018-01-06   0.0
4   2018-01-07   0.0
..         ...   ...
744 2020-01-17   0.0
745 2020-01-18   0.0
746 2020-01-19   0.0
747 2020-01-20   0.0
748 2020-01-21   0.0
```

В целом, есть вся информация о продажах.

Answer (score 3):

Вы, очевидно, совсем недавно занимаетесь анализом данных. Вам следует понять одну вещь. Любая библиотека машинного обучения -- это не чёрный ящик, который творит магию. Это конкретный алгоритм, который решает конкретную задачу с конкретными данными. Если данные вы подаёте не те, для которых предназначен алгоритм, то можете получить всё, что угодно.

Таким образом, Вам следует, для начала, понять, что Вы хотите. Понять, что хочет бизнес. Проанализировать глазами зависимости, которые есть в данных. И лишь потом, тренировать классификатор или регрессор на этих зависимостях.

Следует также отметить, что далеко не все задачи могут быть эффективно решены с помощью технологии машинного обучения. Также, следует отметить, что существуют задачи, которые в принципе нельзя решить. Например, вряд ли Вы на исторических данных по котировкам акций Газпрома сможете предсказать прогноз погоды. Да, связь может быть. Но это не то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Вы правы, для меня это пока что черный ящик (с другой стороны, я не знаю, как пролить свет внутрь этого ящика). Но результат нужен здесь и сейчас.

Мне кажется, имея исторические данные продаж вполне возможно предсказывать будущий объем продаж. Вопрос только в том, что я не знаю, как это делать иначе

Comment: Поищите зависимости в данных. Сделайте бейзлайн и попытайтесь его улучшить. Например, попробуйте предсказывать то, что было в предыдущий шаг

Answer (score 1):

Помимо абсолютно правильно предыдущего ответа, добавлю несколько библиотек -

- модуль statsmodels.tsa.statespace модель sarimax
- модуль statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters  модель Хольта
- модуль statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters модель  ExponentialSmoothing  (включает модель Хольта-Винтерса)
- библиотека Prophet от Facebook
- LSTM в Kerаs

-.....

Только как вам сказали выше - не ждите чуда и "*Мне кажется, имея исторические данные продаж вполне возможно предсказывать будущий объем продаж*." -  не совсем правильный тезис. Это действительно возможно, но чтобы это сделать -  надо не поверхностно  разобраться с темой.

Comment: Зря Вы предложили человеку другие либы. Он же ща ломонётся их пробовать. И с вероятностью а.п.н 1 получит очередную фигню. Либо, что ещё грустнее, он получит что-то более или менее осмысленное, а потом к нему бизнес с горящей попой пребежит и сообщит, что прогноз не сбылся (=

Comment: Ну так сколько не агитируй на форумах, что DS это не игрушки, и надо сначала хорошенько подготовиться, а потом прыгать со скалы - нам же никто не верит.  Пусть попробуют, не запрещать-же.   А что толку не будет - так мы же с вами его предупредили :-). Главное, что-бы бизнес с горячим паяльником не прибежал, но то такое.

Comment: Так, к слову. Я тоже раньше считал, что это чёрный ящик в который все загрузить можно и уаля.. Как дело дошло до боевых задач, меня очень быстро начало от всего этого воротить. И я вернулся к сервисам. DS должен быть планомерен. Это этап становления любого проекта. Когда сделано уже всё, что можно: настроена инфра, дженкинс-херенкинс. Можно делать DS